# FilterOperator NOT IN

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

`com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query.FilterOperator` enum does not have a `NOT_IN` value. All other operations are possible (equal, not equal and all inequalities). Is it possible to create `FilterPredicate` with that behaviour (e.g., `"id", notIn(), new int[] { 3, 4, 7 }`, where `notIn()` is something that will make the query return all values except for those whose id's were found in the list given)? If not, them how can I query the datastore like that? Something like negating the `FilterPredicate`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't (as far as I know) server-side support for that type of query. Your best bet for simulating it client-side is to merge the result of three queries: one for elements below the min of the set, one for elements above the max of the set, and one for for [min..max] where you perform the `not in` in code on the client side.

(Added) You can perform all three queries in parallel to save wall time. A challenge will emerge if any of the queries returns a sufficiently large number of entities to either blow memory or exceed time limits.

Comment: I'm currently doing it after fetching all the data. But I need to fetch all possible values (there is another filter, the client, but even though, all entities of the given client), and that is not very efficent. I can't use that min..max ideia in all scnarios either, because in some the elements are not  numbers. I'll use it in the numeric ones, though, that is a nice catch I hadn't even thought of.